# When does an operator from $\ell_1$ to itself factor through $\ell_p$?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I would like to know whether a given operator from $\ell_1$ to itself, given by a matrix $A$, factors through $\ell_p$, for $p>1$.Does anyone know any references/results on this topic? I am specially interested on the case where the factor from $\ell_p$ to $\ell_1$ is a diagonal operator
Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in $p\le 2$, $p\ge 2$, or both?

Comment: There is a necessary condition: for $p>1$, any operator from $\ell_p$ to $\ell_1$ is compact (Pitt's theorem) and so any operator on $\ell_1$ that factors through $\ell_p$ must also be compact.

Comment: Everything is laid out in chapter 9 of the book of Diestel, Jarchow, and Tonge. They discuss factoring through some $L_p$ space, but this is the same as factoring through $\ell_p$ for  compact operators.